# C105i tablet won't start up

Tags: boot, tablet, crashes

I have an off-the-shelf Chinese call-touch c105i android tablet with an all-winner a10 CPU.

Out of nowhere, it crashed and won't start up. When I turn it on, it just gets stuck in the logo screen.

When I enter the reset mode (you know by pressing the volume up and power button together) and choose the factory reset mode, it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Also, when I try to wipe the data, it says that it cannot open the log and install files.

What's the deal in here? I'd like you guys to know that there's no rooting involved in here. Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

Download the firmware from this site: http://pan.baidu.com/s/1c06Hrck

```
et-86v2g-a23-v1.5
2014.10.13
```

Then download PhoenixSuit and use the .img file to flash the tablet.
Make sure you follow the instructions perfectly because entering into download mode can be hard.

Comment: does that work with a10 cpu?